# c++ error while compiling with both clang++ and g++

Tags: c++, g++, llvm, llvm-clang, clang++

I am working on a project which modifies the control flow of user program. I am using llvm for this. At the end I generate a set of .s files using clang++. Then I use g++ to merge them all. I cant use the clang++ (instead of g++) as its giving a lot of errors at this stage (this is not the current problem)

For c programs (gcc and clang), things are working perfectly. But for c++ user code (g++, clang++) I am getting the following error when I execute

`g++ -O3 -rdynamic *.s -o main.exe -Wa,-Iressource -lstdc++ -lm -ldl`

```
/tmp/ccUdIbL3.o:(.ctors+0x0): undefined reference to `global constructors keyed to a'
/tmp/cch9k7on.o: In function `global constructors keyed to a':
_GLOBAL__I_a.optin:(.text.startup+0x1): undefined reference to `__cxx_global_var_init'
/tmp/ccvYrG8J.o:(.ctors+0x0): undefined reference to `global constructors keyed to a'
/tmp/cccPFs4G.o:(.ctors+0x0): undefined reference to `global constructors keyed to a'
```

As per my search on internet, for most of the people this error occurred because they use clang (instead of clang++).

**Clang**

> clang --version
>   clang version 3.1 (branches/release_31)
>
> Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
>
> Thread model: posix

**g++**

> g++ --version
>
> g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) 4.7.3

I have no idea of where the actual problem is. But I know that if I simply use clang++ to generate *.s files and then use g++ (without my llvm pass) it works fine. Since it llvm dont complain till the end then g++ does, I dont know where the actual error occurred. As I said earlier if the original code was "C" (by using clang and gcc) it works fine.

Any help on how to proceed or a solution to solve the problem is appreciated.

Specially what might lead to (in this context)

1. undefined reference to __cxx_global_var_init
2. global constructors keyed to a

Comment: *I cant use the clang++ as its giving a lot of errors at this stage (this is not the current problem)* -- That is precisely the problem. You need to use clang++ rather than clang for c++ code.

Comment: You shouldn't need to link `libstdc++` and `libm` explicitly. The `g++` command should imply that.

Comment: @DavidHammen No. That's not what I meant. I meant in the last stage instead of g++ I cant use clang++. I hope its clear. (clang and gcc are only used for c codes in the project, I use clang++ and g++ for cpp)

Comment: @KerrekSB Thank you for the tip. could you please give a direction on how to procceed

Comment: What operating system are you using? What versions of gcc and clang are you using? Did you install them properly? Your question doesn't contain any of this information.

Comment: @DavidHammen All the info of g++ and clang version are there on the original post. As for OS, its Ubuntu x86_64. Also yes its not the problem with installation. I am sure of that